# Creating a ssh vpn with multiple peers behind firewalls

Tags: ssh, vpn, openvpn

I followed the instructions found 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH_VPN
and setup a ssh vpn connection from work(behind a firewall) to a 3rd party machine with a public IP. Now I need to setup a second connection from home(behind a firewall) to the 3rd party machine with a public IP. I tried following the instructions by using a tun1 instead of tun0 to add a second and separate connection but neither the client nor the server would allow me to create the tun1 interface.

My question is how can I add the second connection to the public IP machine? Is it possible to add multiple pointtopoint entries since it isn't possible to add multiple tun entries? This didn't work for me but perhaps I was doing it wrong.

I tried to use openvpn for this but my work firewall has something screwing it up. It would stay up for 2 minutes then down for 2 back and forth. Very frustrating.

well thanks